# Python Google drive API cannot insert media file using mediaFileUpload

Tags: python, google-api

I tried submitting this to Google support but they referred me to stack overflow but there's an issue when running the insert function for the Google Drive API using the python library googleapiclient.

Python Broken API Function Call

When trying to insert a MediaFileUpload as per the instructions in

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

How do I submit lines of code in a comment?

UPDATED:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
media_body = MediaFileUpload('test.csv', mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel', resumable=True)

body = {
'title': 'test.csv',
'description': 'test description',
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
}
file = service.files().insert(body=body,media_body=media_body).execute()
```

It doesn't actually work, you keep getting an error message saying a string or MediaFile type is required
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 692, in method
    raise TypeError('media_filename must be str or MediaUpload.')

Does anyone know why media_body can't be MediaFileUpload when the documentation clearly says use MediaFileUpload?

Comment: I have a program very similar to this that is currently working. Can you update your question with more of your code?

Comment: Sure that's not a problem.

Comment: Comments formatting is sort of limited - best is to update the code snippet in your original question.

Comment: I've updated the code, there's a bit of redundancy in the body and media_body request but that should be ok.

Comment: How are you authenticating?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 through the OAuth2WebServerFlow function and passing in the client_id, client_secret and enabling the Google Drive scope from the API.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The only thing that I've noticed so far that might be relevant: that error message is on line 757 of python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in my environment. I just checked and I have the most recent pip installable version:
$ pip show google-api-python-client
---
Name: google-api-python-client
Version: 1.4.2

perhaps try upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: Awesome, that works! It seems it was due to the fact that I was still running google-api-python-client 1.3 in our python 2.7 libraries so I upgraded to 1.4.2 and it worked. I don't know how to approve the answer so I'm just going to copy your answer and mark it as answered.

Comment: Nice! Want me to write up the answer that worked?

Comment: Yes, please I deleted my answer so please repost your answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments thread, here was the answer that ended up resolving the issue:

Upgrade to the latest google-api-python-client (version 1.4.2 as of this writing).

Comment: I can't up the answer because my scores too low but thanks that resolved it. I'll leave the code in case anyone needs to upload files into Google Drive using the API for python.

Comment: Yes, that code was useful - my previous version only worked for text files, so it seems like it may help someone else.